# Soft body render heavily stutters regardless whether simulation has been baked

Tags: rendering, animation, collision, soft-body

I have no idea as to why the soft body collision simulation keeps stuttering exclusively in render process. Regardless of whether I remove subdivision modifier, bake all dynamics or choose a different render engine, the resulting sequence is generally blocky and lacks half of the animation on some frames, even though the viewport preview is quite smooth.

Here is the link to the file https://easyupload.io/rri98j.

Comment: You had enabled the sequencer with an image inside, making the render fully void, I had to disable it to actually be able to render. But once done, I don't see any difference between the [viewport and final render](https://imgur.com/a/zOPHODN).

Comment: Apparently this is a hardware issue, since after rebooting today and opening the same project any type of render went absolutely fine. I'll delete the question a bit later, just in case.

Comment: No need to delete, you have a solution for that issue : post it as an answer ;)